# Runtime dependency included in war

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am a little surprised: I declared a dependency in maven pom as runtime and it was still included in war.
I honestly expected it not to do this...
I used junit just for the purpose of demonstration...:)
For example:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Thanks,
Roxana

Comment: can you show us yer POM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some maven-scopes:

- if the dependency is needed in production and has to be delivered along with the application use scope `runtime`
- if the dependency is needed only for (unit-)testing and should not be delivered use scope `test`
- if the dependency is needed in production but is already part of the container (e.g. tomcat, JBOSS) use scope `provided`

Comment: as mentioned above <scope>provided</scope> will make sure that the dependency is not included in the war file. If you want to put the dependency to a specific location. use maven-copy-dependencies plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you want something at runtime then it has to be in the package. Otherwise where will the software know where to find it.

What were you expecting? And most importantly, why are you including JUnit in Runtime? It should be in test scope.

Comment: @Roxana Why? Provided means it's provided by something other than your artifact. Runtime means it's required at runtime, but isn't provided by anything else.

Comment: so...you can very well declare it as compile...it's just about finesse

Comment: Usually yes, but runtime is special in that it makes the dependency appear in the deployment and in the test classpath, but NOT in the compile classpath. Me personally I find it a bit too much going into dependency micro-management to use it to be honest.